# Условия в JavaScript (React framework)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Пытаюсь понять почему счётчик не работает при таком условии

```
if(!this.state.counter === 50) {
   this.setState({
  counter: this.state.counter + 1
   })
} else {
  console.log("Limit reached")
}
```

если пишу вот так то всё нормально

```
if(this.state.counter === 50) {
  console.log("Limit reached")
} else {
  this.setState({
  counter: this.state.counter + 1
   })
}
```

Comment: не там ставишь `!`

Comment: if (!(this.state.counter  === 50)) или if(this.state.counter != 50) {